# How to detect keyType Boolean or not from Plist in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, plist

I have a requirement where I want to detect if the value for a specific key is of type `Boolean` or not in the plist. Using the following code I am loading the plist from the bundle:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
id developer = [dict objectForKey:@“iOSDeveloper];
```

My plist look like this:

```
   Key                       Type                             value
iosDeveloper                Boolean                            YES
```

if user change the type to `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, ect… instead of `Boolean`, I want to print log like `select type boolean for iOSDeveloper key`

Comment: Boolean is an `NSNumber` by another name. What did you try to detect array / dictionary?

Comment: i did like this if ([developer isKindOfClass[NSNumber class]]). Here the problem is if i select Type NSArray,NSDictionary.... it print  log like "select type boolean for iOSDeveloper key". if i select type NSNumber it is not giving me log.

Comment: The best you can do is to allow `NSNumber` but check the value is `0` or `1` and log if not...